# Get foreign key fields in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Accessing my API endpoint I get something like this:

```
{
    place: "https://example.com/api/places/998/?format=json",
    item: "Stone Fruit Salad",
    description: "greens • fennel • cucumber"
},
{
    place: "https://example.com/api/places/999/?format=json",
    item: "Elote",
    description: "sweet corn • raddish • goat milk feta • pepita • chipotle yogurt dressing • (can be made vegan)"
}
```

What I'd like to do is have the place `name` and other fields available from this endpoint, instead of the the URL to another endpoint. Is this possible? Something like this:

```
{
    place_name: "Place 1",
    place_website: "example.com",
    item: "Stone Fruit Salad",
    description: "greens • fennel • cucumber"
},
{
    place_name: "Place 2",
    place_website: "example.com",
    item: "Elote",
    description: "sweet corn • raddish • goat milk feta • pepita • chipotle yogurt dressing • (can be made vegan)"
}
```

### Files

serializer.py

```
from ..models import MenuItem
from rest_framework import serializers


class MenuItemSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MenuItem
        fields = ('place','item','description')
```

views.py (api views)

```
from ..models import MenuItem
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import MenuItemSerializer


class MenuItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MenuItem.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MenuItemSerializer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **`ModelSerializer`** instead of **`HyperlinkedModelSerializer`** as,

```
class MenuItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    place_name = serializers.CharField(source='place.name')
    place_website = serializers.CharField(source='place.website')

    class Meta:
        model = MenuItem
        fields = ('place_name', 'place_website', 'item', 'description')
```

**Reference**
1. [Serializer's `source` argument](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source)
2. [**`ModelSerializer`** class](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer)

Comment: @smilebomb Added few references related to the answer. Take a look :)